# want the button onClick to getDay web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to onClick a buttom so that it automatically figures what day the machine is in and find the website according to it (e.g. if it is Sunday, it will find Sunday.html)

Being a beginner at HTML, CSS and Javascript, I got the code from w3schools and changed the output to just .html - obviously, it didn't work. I was wondering is there any simple way of correcting this?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var d = new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday.html";
weekday[1]="Monday.html";
weekday[2]="Tuesday.html";
weekday[3]="Wednesday.html";
weekday[4]="Thursday.html";
weekday[5]="Friday.html";
weekday[6]="Saturday.html";

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=weekday[d.getDay()];
}
</script>
```

I've also did another way through using if statement,

```
if (currentDay == 6)
{
window.location = 'saturday.html';
}
            }
            else if (currentDay == 0)
            {
                window.location = 'sunday.html';
            }
```

etc.

Again, it doesn't seem to work. Is there simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `getUTCDay()` if you have problems with time zone.

Comment: it's not the time zone that I have problem, more to do with onClick button not displaying the day page at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method of doing window.location to the url is correct.

I did minor modification to your code. Please try the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/QK2TL/1/).
Open the debug console to see the messages.

```
var d = new Date();
var loc = weekday[d.getDay()];
alert("about to navigate to " + weekday[d.getDay()]);
window.location = loc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction()
{
var d = new Date();
var weekday=[];

weekday[0]="Sunday.html";
weekday[1]="Monday.html";
weekday[2]="Tuesday.html";
weekday[3]="Wednesday.html";
weekday[4]="Thursday.html";
weekday[5]="Friday.html";
weekday[6]="Saturday.html";

return weekday[d.getDay()];
}


window.location = myFunction();
```